# I would like my application that runs in the background was not closed by Android

Tags: java, android, service

My application has a service that performs a get in the especific URL every 30 seconds. The service is so configured in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
  android:name="com.analisesistemas.taxiweb.android.alarm.MyAlarmReceiver"
  android:process=":remote" >
</receiver>
<service
  android:name="com.suporte.motoweb.chegaja.MyTestService"
  android:exported="false" />
```

The service starts this way by my application:

```
// Setup a recurring alarm every half minute
public void scheduleAlarm() {
// Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmReceiver.class);

// Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Setup periodic alarm every 5 seconds
long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

// First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
// Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, TIMER, pIntent);
}
```

The method scheduleAlarm() is called in onCreate() of my main Activity.

The problem is that when I press the home button (to minimize my app) so I can use other apps like facebook and instagram ... I notice that
my application stops running (android closed my application likely to save memory).

Really I've tried every way, but Android closed my app when it runs in the background. Not immediately, it is after a few minutes!

How can I prevent my app is terminated by the Android operating system ?? I need to leave it running indefinitely !! :(

thank ever since attention

Comment: A GET request every 30 seconds will result in Excessive data usage and Battery drain which will result in all users uninstalling your app.  Elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve and I can give you a better solution of how best to approach it https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html

Comment: This behaviour could be ROM dependent, and not Android (in general) dependent. I remember there was a similar bug in 4.0.1 if I recall correctly, but it has been fixed a long time ago in later versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement instead of Sticky Service I would recommend you to use [GCM Network Manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) which uses `JobSchedular API` for Lollipop and upper version and similar compatible way for lower version of android as well. For Periodic Task it would do all the difficult steps for you and you can mainly concentrate on Business logic.

```
PeriodicTask task = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
        .setService(MyTaskService.class)
        .setTag(TASK_TAG_PERIODIC)
        .setPeriod(30L)
        .build();

mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(task);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a broadcast in onDestroy() method of your service, and start service when you receive broadcast

Comment: Hi, how can I do this ? you have an example?

Comment: Sorry，It's just an idea. But i don't think it is difficult. As it is difficult to prevent system stopping you app, you can restart when app is stopped. When Service stop, it must run ondestroy()，so you can send a broadcast in ondestroy() method, and register a broadcast receiver which start the service when it receive the stop broadcast

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it is really good idea to set http request each 30 seconds? As @JustinSlade mentioned this will lead the phone to excessive battery usage and bad user experience.

Besides, it is not clear what is wrong with your current mechanism - from first look `AlarmManager` should trigger `BroadcastReceiver`, which, as I understand run `Service` where request is performing (and, maybe, reschedule alarm). So, what is wrong here? Don't you receive broadcasted intent?

Anyway, it is really ugly approach and I would suggest you to use `Google Cloud Messaging` and notify application only when new data is available. In order to increase priority of your application process you also can use `setForeground` in your `Service`, but this requires to provide UI in notification panel.